# Excel: How to add a column to current worksheet which is stored in another file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3 excel files each containing only one column. First one has customer name, second one has item name and third one has bill amount. I want to merge these to another file called all_details which has all of these columns i.e. customer name, item name and bill amount. What is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whether there is a corresponding relationship in each row of data in 3 Excel files?
Do you want to merge the 3 columns of data into “all_details” file and under existing data? Or do you want the 3 columns to exist separately? Maybe you could use "Shift+Ctrl+↓“ to select one column each time, and then copy and paste it to all_details file.

Answer (score 0):

Just select (you can click on the top of column) all records in some column Ctrl + X or Ctrl + C and then paste it to another sheet as second or third column next to the rest.